# "Induction on Complexity" Problem

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Let $F,G$ be two distinct atomic formulae. Show that no formula that can be formed from $F,G$ using just the conditional $\to$ is logically equivalent to $\neg F \vee \neg G$. We are then told that we can find a property not had by $\neg F \vee \neg G$ and use induction to show that this property is had by any formula formed from $F,G$ using just $\to$.

Wikipedia defines logically equivalent as so: two statements are equivalent if they have the same truth value in every model

Hence, I would imagine I could just use the standard model of arithmetic, and fine the property that was asked for. However, there is definitely more to this, but I don't know how to do it because I have not ever worked on any induction on complexity problems. There is only a few relevant examples in Boolos and Jeffrey's book, but they all seem very vague to me. Could someone please explain this process to me and show me how one would solve this problem? Thank you.

Edit: This is how my text defines induction

"Base Step: Atomic formulas have the property.
Induction Step: If a more complex formula is formed by applying a logical operator to a simpler formula or formulas, then, assuming (as induction hypothesis) that the simpler formula or formulas have the property, so does the more complex formula. The induction step will usually be divided into cases, according as the operator is ∼ or & or ∨ or ∀ or ∃."

Answer (score 2):

I believe the idea is to use induction on the number of times the operator $\to$ appears in the formula.
As a hint: what happens when both $F, G$ are True?

Comment: Hey Benji, I just did an edit. Do you still think we are inducting on the operator?

Comment: yes. in your case the operator is $\to$

Comment: Whoa lol sorry man I'm half asleep I don't know why I didn't see that in the definition. You think if I give it a shot at a proof you could check it out?

Comment: yes go ahead and give it a shot

Comment: In response to your hint when both $F,G$ are true, then we have that $\neg F \vee \neg G$ is always false right?

Comment: Correct. And what does the formula that uses only $\to$ evaluate to?

Comment: Always true! :)

Comment: Do I have to fix $F$ and $G$ under an interpretation before I begin induction? That is the thing I am most confused about...

Comment: Show the basis which is $F \to G$ and $G \to F$ and then assume that $X,Y$ are simpler formulas consisting of $F,G$ and the operator $\to$ with the property that when $F,G$ are true so is the formula and show that in that case both complex formulas $X \to Y$ and $Y \to X$ hold that property

Comment: What about the part where I am supposed to "find a property not had by $\neg F\vee \neg G$"

Comment: That's it - when $F,G$ are true, $\neg F \vee \neg G$ is false while any formula built with $F, G$ and $\to$ is true

Comment: Awesome thanks a bunch Benji!